# how to change the picker outer border color .net maui

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

Hey how can i change the ugly outer borders on win ui .net maui picker? Is there any way to disable it? Or maybe change the color?

Also what is this weird bug when you hover over the picker the texts change colors?

Comment: Out of the box, those controls are very hard to customize. You can always try to write your own control, or write bunch of platform specific code to customize the way they look. There are some answers already "how to customize picker". I prefer to live with the ugly borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picker's windows natvie control is combobox. So you can use the handler to disable the border:

```
public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell(); 
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PickerHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Picker), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var combobox = handler.PlatformView;
            combobox.BorderBrush = null;
            combobox.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(0);     
#endif
        });
    }
```

Or you can change its color by change the windows native combobox style. Just add the following code to the `\Platforms\Windows\App.xaml`:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="MauiAppTest.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:MauiAppTest.WinUI">
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBorderBrush" Color="#Ff0000" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="#Ff0000" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBorderBrushPressed" Color="#Ff0000" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

But I can't reproduce the problem you said about the text color changed. You can check [the default style of the combobox](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ComboBox/ComboBox_themeresources.xaml#L386).

Comment: hey thank you so much. do you know how to change the arrow down color? or how to disable it?

Comment: You can hide it by set the color as transparent. Such as `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground" Color="#000000" />`. @FardinFarnezhad

Comment: And did this answer your new question on the SO? Or did you want make the picker like an entry for all the platforms? @FardinFarnezhad

Comment: it actually did but i still encountered wierd bugs so i decided to hide the picker behind an entry untill the bugs get resolved i think this is the best way but thank you so much your answer actually opened my eyes. sorry for bothering you .

Comment: You are welcome and I had a mistake. The transparent color should be `#0000` not `#000000`. @FardinFarnezhad